# net::oauth return 401 unauthorized even though curl works

Tags: perl, oauth

I am attempting to request a token from https://launchpad.net, according to the docs all it wants is a POST to /+request-token with the form encoded values of oauth_consumer_key, oauth_signature, and oauth_signature_method. Providing those items via curl works as expected:

```
curl --data "oauth_consumer_key=test-app&oauth_signature=%26&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT" https://launchpad.net/+request-token
```

However, when i attempt to do it through my perl script it is giving me a 401 unauthorized error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use YAML qw(DumpFile);
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Net::OAuth;
$Net::OAuth::PROTOCOL_VERSION = Net::OAuth::PROTOCOL_VERSION_1_0A;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use Data::Dumper;
use Browser::Open qw(open_browser);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my ($home)           = glob '~';
my $cfg              = "$home/.lp-auth.yml";
my $access_token_url = q[https://launchpad.net/+access-token];
my $authorize_path   = q[https://launchpad.net/+authorize-token];

sub consumer_key { 'lp-ua-browser' }
sub request_url {"https://launchpad.net/+request-token"}

my $request = Net::OAuth->request('consumer')->new(
    consumer_key     => consumer_key(),
    consumer_secret  => '',
    request_url      => request_url(),
    request_method   => 'POST',
    signature_method => 'PLAINTEXT',
    timestamp        => time,
    nonce            => nonce(),
);

$request->sign;
print $request->to_url;

my $res = $ua->request(POST $request->to_url, Content $request->to_post_body);
my $token;
my $token_secret;
print Dumper($res);
if ($res->is_success) {
    my $response =
      Net::OAuth->response('request token')->from_post_body($res->content);
    $token        = $response->token;
    $token_secret = $response->token_secret;
    print "request token ",       $token,        "\n";
    print "request token secret", $token_secret, "\n";
    open_browser($authorize_path . "?oauth_token=" . $token);
}
else {
    die "something broke ($!)";
}
```

I tried both with `$request->sign` and without it as i dont think that is required during the request token phase. Anyway any help with this would be appreciated.

Update, switched to LWP::UserAgent and had to pass in both POST and Content :

```
my $res = $ua->request(POST $request->to_url, Content $request->to_post_body);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm not able to verify from my tablet but with recent Perl you should install and use

```
use LWP::Protocol::https;
```

http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2011/07/now-you-need-lwpprotocolhttps.html